# Show my apps statistics on my website from the appstores.?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, app-store

I am creating few native apps for Blackberry, Android and Iphone. And I am also planning to publish those on their respective app-stores. I have my own website to promote those apps.

The information that i need to know is, Is it possible to pull the statistics about my apps from the app stores and show that on my website.

Is there any API's or something else there to show that..

(statistics == no. of times downloaded, viewed, purchased etc..)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it in quite a while, but there's an existing open source project for interfacing with the Marketplace info:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

That just gives you access to the same stats as you would see in the Marketplace app on a device though, not exact download numbers.

Comment: yes, Thanks Mike.
Do you have any info about itunes store and blackberry appworld?

Comment: iTunes doesn't put estimated download numbers in the publicly available info the way that Marketplace does. But you can always get more exact numbers out of iTunes Connect or using one of the third party services like Distimo or Heartbeat that pull the stats together.

Comment: Wow great, I am gonna test Distimo since it supports all the three stores. 

In the mean time if you got any other idea, please comment here.
Thank you very much ya.